# Progress bar automatically after choose file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I would like to appearing the progress bar without clicking button. After choose file (after double click the file uploaded), it should be running the progress bar. but in my code not work. please help me..

My code:

```js
function move() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("myBar"); 
  var width = 1;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 10);
  function frame() {
      if (width >= 100) {
          clearInterval(id);
      } else {
          width++; 
          elem.style.width = width + '%'; 
      }
  }
}
```

```css
#myProgress {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: grey;
}
#myBar {
    width: 1%;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
 <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
  <tr>
   <label style="text-align:left;" class="control-label col-md-3">Surat Permohonan<span class="required"> * </span></label>
   <div class="col-md-4">
    <td><input class="input-group" type="file" accept="image/*, .pdf" name="file" style="width:100%" required title="Masukan minimal satu file">
     <div id="myProgress">
       <div id="myBar">10%</div>
     </div>
    </td>
   </div>
   <td><i class="fa fa-question-circle tooltips" data-html="true" data-original-title='<b>A. UNTUK PENDAFTAR INDIVIDU</b><br>1. Upload scan KTP yang masih berlaku. Apabila tidak ada bisa menggunakan SIM/Paspor yang masih berlaku.<br>2. Upload surat pengantar dari individu yang menerangkan ringkasan keperluan pengajuan proposal.<br><br><b>B. UNTUK PENDAFTAR ORGANISASI</b><br>1. Upload scan Surat Keterangan yang menerangkan legalitas/status hukum organisasi yang bersangkutan. Misal: SK dari kemenkumham tentang lembaga hukum, atau SK Rektor tentang organisasi kemahasiswaan.<br>2. Upload surat pengantar dari organisasi yang menerangkan ringkasan keperluan pengajuan proposal.<br><br><b>C. UNTUK PENDAFTAR PEMERINTAH</b><br>1. Upload surat pengantar resmi dari lembaga bersangkutan yang menerangkan ringkasan keperluan pengajuan proposal.<br><br><b>TRAVEL GRANT (Individu/organisasi/pemerintah)</b><br>Pilihan ini muncul ketika pemohon (dalam bentuk apapun) memilih pilihan "travel grant" pada kolom isian "jenis bantuan" pada menu "Lembar Isian Kegiatan". Adapun data yang harus diupload ketika opsi ini dipilih adalah:<br>1. Upload surat undangan dari pihak penyelenggara.<br>2. Upload dokumen yang menerangkan status pemohon; misal sebagai finalis festival film, atau sebagai pemenang lomba.<br>Apabila kedua dokumen di atas terlampir pada satu dokumen/surat yang sama, silakan upload file yang sama pada kedua pilihan yang disediakan.<br><br>Format dokumen yang diunggah dalam menu ini lebih baik disamakan dalam bentuk PDF.' data-container="body"></i></td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</div>
```

Sorry for my bad english. I'm new on PHP. Thanks for helps.

Comment: I don't see that you call your `move()` function anywhere?

Comment: That's not how the input type='file' element operates.

Comment: actually move() function on button, but i would like to using no button